# Horizontal and vertical scrollbar in Android with tablelayout?

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

Please help me if you know how to add both scrollbar.
First of all i clear to all.
I added both scroll bar in tablelayout but main problem is i m using dynamic data for filling tablerow. So, if there is only one record so horizontal scroll view top after the data. but i want to show horizontal in bottom and also show vertical.

Thanks 
Prashant

Comment: I think you are asking how to get the horizontal scrollbar to show up all the way at the bottom of the TableLayout, instead of being underneath the data.  Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code..

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrllvwNo1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
//TextView
//Button
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this way and its run perfectly for me.

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/layout" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset">
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalView" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgView" android:maxHeight="280dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"   
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook" android:maxWidth="280dip"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_height="280dip" 
            android:layout_width="280dip"></ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the attribute `scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack` respectively `scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack`

Here the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack

Comment: But i can't getting proper your ans. please explain in detail.